# UITableView will not respond tap after scroll horizontally

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView which is embedded in the root view of the ViewController. This UITableView contains multiple columns. And these columns can not be shown in one screen, so I make the UITableView can scroll horizontally. Here is the code which make the tableview scrolling horizontally:

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        CGSize size = self.tableView.contentSize;
        size.width = 450;
        self.tableView.contentSize = size;
        [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
    }
```

This works fine and the table can scroll horizontally and vertically. And in the original screen(where no scroll happening), I can select one row and the selected row can be highlighted.

What my problem is: If I scroll the UITableView a little bit left, and in the area where is not shown before scrolling, the tap event cannot be responded by the UITableView. And thus, the row under my finger will not be selected and highlighted. But I can scroll if I swipe in the same area.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? Appreciated for your comments and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I think this is a bug of UITableView.  I get a workaround for the problem by subclass UITableView. Here it is:

```
    // in my own UITableView subclass .m file
    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        NSLog(@"MonthDetailTableView: touchesEnded");

        UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];

        if (point.x < self.frame.size.width)
        {
            [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
        }
        else
        {
            // if not adjust by mod, the NSIndexPath returned by indexPathForRowAtPoint 
            // will be nil. I think this is a bug of UITableView
            point.x = (int)point.x % (int)self.frame.size.width;
            NSIndexPath *path = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
            [self selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

            if (self.delegate != nil &&
                [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)])
            {
                [self.delegate tableView:self didSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem and there is always a simple way to do a complex problem.Your required functionality can be achieved by using [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/).
In your UITableViewCell add [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/).In this approach your code will get cleaner and you can achieve your functionality without any headache.
Here is very simple [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/) about UICollectionView.
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Comment: thanks for your post. In this way, all of the data can be shown in the screen and no need to scroll horizontally, right? But for my scenario, the data must be listed in one row, as they are real spreadsheet, for example, the examination results of students in my classroom.

Comment: you also can use scroll view with paging and the collectionview, it will make your collectionview become 2 page

Comment: @Tj3n I will try this way. But on the other hand, could you comment the issue in my solution?